# Nginx giving 403 forbidden on static

Tags: nginx

I have been hitting my head for two days trying to get Nginx to work using a reverse proxy. I am using a Bokeh server that listens for connections on `192.168.X.X` from `www.somesite.com:443`.

Issue 1:
My Nginx conf file is below and I get a `403 Forbidden` when accessing `/static/` files. Here is how I call the Bokeh server: http://www.somesite.ai:443/5007/user_5007

Issue 2:
TBD after I can solve issue 1.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.somesite.ai;

    #The internal IP of the VM that hosts your Apache config

    location /{    
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(\d+)/([^/]+)) {
            proxy_pass   http://192.168.X.XXX:$1/$2/;       
        }    

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;           
    }

    location ~ ^/(\d+)/static/ {
        try_files $uri  /bokehstatic/static/;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error logs

Comment: I was able to resolve this by setting autoindex to on.  The second issue now is :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290307/bokeh-sever-with-nginx-gives-blank-white-screen (this is the harder one).  Thanks!