# Bokeh Sever with NGINX gives Blank white screen

Tags: bokeh

I am using `NGINX` with `bokeh` server.  I connect to the internal bokeh listener but on the external site i see just a blank white screen.  The view page source shows the Bokeh code, the css and js static links work but no plots??? Can somebody help me here?

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: Nothing of relevance in the console..it almost seems like the inline javascript is being ignored by the browsers.  Note when I connect "directly" to the Bokeh app (without NGINX in the middle) say over port 80 or 443 i see my plot in Chrome (or other browsers).  So, it has to be something i am configuring incorrectly in NGINX...

Comment: note Bokeh app is running on Windows 10

Comment: Much more indormation, e.g. your nginx config and network layout is needed in order to help, as well as any terminal or log output

Comment: Thanks...attached is the NGINX.conf  #user nobody;

worker_processes 4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include C:/XXX/wwwroot/XX/nginx-1.13.5/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf; 

}

Comment: here is the virtual host file:

Comment: server {
    listen 443; 
    error_log  C:/CORE_FILES/nginxlog/error.log debug;    
     location /{    
  if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(\d+)/([^/]+)) {
   proxy_pass   http://192.168.0.101:$1/$2/;     
  }      
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
 location ~ ^/(\d+)/static/ {
 #location /static/ {
 autoindex on;
 alias /bokehstatic/static/;      
 }
}

Comment: Does anyone have a working .conf with NGINX and Bokeh server that works?